# What are the c++ function signature additional keywords?

Tags: c++, function, methods, keyword, signature

I found an example of [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html#sig) native function written in c++ which signature is following

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_ReadFile_loadFile(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);
```

What are these `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` keywords? How do you call them? What do they do?

Answer (score 4):

`JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` are macros used to specify the calling and linkage convention of both JNI functions and native method implementations. The programmer must place the JNIEXPORT macro before the function return type and the JNICALL macro between the function name and the return type.

For more information visit: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html

From "12.4 Constants"

> JNIEXPORT and JNICALL are macros used to specify the calling and linkage convention of both JNI functions and native method implementations. The programmer must place the JNIEXPORT macro before the function return type and the JNICALL macro between the function name and the return type.